# how to write review on Android market using app?

Tags: android

I want users of my application to be able to write review on market place. I want to linkup my application with android market place.I am trying this way but I am getting error

code

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

and error like

```
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.stress }
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3067)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2847)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at com.stress.More$1.onItemClick(More.java:63)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-04 16:24:15.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(661):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you running this on emulator?

Comment: you need to test this on real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are invoking this from a different class, then check in your manifest if you have mentioned that activity name or not. ActivityNotFoundException occurs when you forget it mention some classes in Manifest file and try to access it.

Try this code too for instance:

```
 Intent marketLaunch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse("YOUR APP'S ANDROID MARKET LINK HERE"));
 startActivity(marketLaunch);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu may want to check out this link ([Open Source Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)) - doesnt do what you want now, but may in the future i.e. integrating market functionality (albeit with a web-based back end) into your app